# Aggregation Pipeline Operators in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to use MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline Operators using Mongoose in nodejs

I am trying to count datewise data using aggregate

```
                  Walkins.aggregate([
                        {
                            $match:{'subscriberId': subsc._id},
                        },{
                            $project:{'date':{ $convert: { input:'$created', to: "date"} },
                        } },{
                            $project:{ 'dates': { $dateToString : { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$created" } }} ,
                        },{
                            $group:{
                                _id:{'date': '$created'} ,
                                walkinsCount :{$sum: 1 }
                            }
                        }

                    ]).then((walkins)=>{    });
```

But it is troughing "MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$convert'" Error

```
                  Walkins.aggregate([
                        {
                            $match:{'subscriberId': subsc._id},
                        },{
                            $project:{'date':{ $toDate:'$created'} },
                        } },{
                            $project:{ 'dates': { $dateToString : { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$created" } }} ,
                        },{
                            $group:{
                                _id:{'date': '$created'} ,
                                walkinsCount :{$sum: 1 }
                            }
                        }

                    ]).then((walkins)=>{    });
```

Comment: anywhere u using `$convert'` ?

Comment: Yeah using in first query & if i use $toDate then it is giving MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$toDate'" Error

Comment: what is your mongoose and mongodb version?

Comment: "mongoose": "^5.1.3",    MongoDB : 3.6.6

Answer (score 2):

`$toDate` is only available in version `4.0` and above. [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#exp._S_toDate), you can see it's written `New in version 4.0.` which means you can't use it with a MongoDB installation of anything lower than version `4.0`.

If you're using Ubuntu and installed MongoDB using `apt install mongodb`, it installs version `3.6.3`.

Check out the official documentation on how to install and run the latest version [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/) for your OS.